# Поиск дружественных пар чисел с помощью циклов

Tags: python, алгоритм, for, теория-чисел

> Составьте программу для решения задачи. Два натуральных числа называются дружественными, если каждое из них равно сумме всех
> делителей другого (само другое число в качестве делителя не
> рассматривается). Например, 220 (1+2+4+5+10+11+20+22+44+55+110=284) и
> 284 (1+2+4+71+142=220) – дружественные числа. Пары необходим о
> выводить по одной в строке, разделяя пробелами. Найти все пары
> натуральных дружественных чисел, меньших 10 000.

Решения на эту задачу уже есть в интернете, но, насколько я понял, они с употреблением массивов, что мне не подходит. Я хотел бы сделать эту задачу только при использовании циклов, вроде у меня и получилось:

```
for i in range(1, 9999):
    for k in range(1, i // 2 + 1):
        if i % k == 0:
            sum1 += k
    for j in range(i + 1, 9999):
        if j == i:
            continue
        for k in range(1, j // 2 + 1):
            if j % k == 0:
                sum2 += k
        if sum1 == j and sum2 == i:
            print(i, j, sep=' ')
    sum1, sum2 = 0, 0
```

Но решение настолько долгое, что я не хочу ждать даже вторую пару чисел. Пожалуйста, помогите с оптимизацией.

Comment: 1. Убрать вложенные циклы, разумеется. 2. Делать цикл до квадратного корня я прибавлять сразу k и i/k (в случае квадратных числе прибавлять только k, понятное дело).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перебираете все пары чисел `1 <= i < j < 10000` и проверяете что `sum_of_proper_divisors(i) = sum_of_proper_divisors(j)`. Технически это правильный способ, но как долго это будет работать? Я взял вашу программу и сделал из неё считалку итераций:

```
c = 0
for i in range(1, 9999):
    for k in range(1, i // 2 + 1):
        c += 1
    for j in range(i + 1, 9999):
        c += j // 2
print(c)
```

> ```
> $ python count-ops.py 
> 166579182499
> ```

167 миллиардов операций. Мой компьютер делает около 10 миллионов итераций в секунду. 16700 секунд - ожидаемое время работы вашего кода.

Вместо двух циклов достаточно одного по `i`. Второе число вычисляется как `j = sum_of_proper_divisors(i)`. Ещё одно вычисление нужно чтобы проверить второе соотношение - `i == sum_of_proper_divisors(j)`. На вскидку, так будет в 10000 раз меньше итераций. Проверяем:

```
def sum_of_proper_divisors(n):
    s = 0
    for k in range(1, n // 2 + 1):
        if n % k == 0:
            s += k
    return s

for i in range(1, 10000):
    j = sum_of_proper_divisors(i)
    if i < j <= n and i == sum_of_proper_divisors(j):
        print(i, j)
```

> ```
> $ time python amicable-numbers.py 
> 220 284
> 1184 1210
> 2620 2924
> 5020 5564
> 6232 6368
>
> real  0m1.582s
> user  0m1.576s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Ваша задача решена. Идем дальше.

*NB: `range(?, 9999)` исключает `9999` из цикла. Вам повезло, это не влияет на результат, но цикл должен быть длиннее на единицу.*

Если к сумме которую мы считаем добавить `n`, то получится сумма всех делителей числа `n` (любое число делится само на себя, но мы этот делитель не учитываем). Для суммы всех делителей есть [функция делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9). Статья про неё написана несколько сложно, но разобраться при желании можно. Сумму всех делителей числа можно выразить как произведение некоторых множителей, которые зависят от разложения этого числа на простые. Получается такая пара функций:

```
def sum_of_divisors(n):
    s = 1
    i = 2
    j = n
    j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
    while i <= j_sqrt:
        if j % i == 0:
            f = 1
            m = 1
            while j % i == 0:
                j //= i
                m *= i
                f += m
            j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
            s *= f
        i += 1
    if j > 1:
        s *= j + 1
    return s


def sum_of_proper_divisors(n):
    return sum_of_divisors(n) - n
```

Получается сложнее чем ваш вариант, зато быстрее. Кроме того это факультатив.

> ```
> $ time python amicable-numbers.py 
> 220 284
> 1184 1210
> 2620 2924
> 5020 5564
> 6232 6368
>
> real  0m0.066s
> user  0m0.064s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

66 миллисекунд, из них 25 - загрузка программы в память.

16 секунд для миллиона:

> ```
> $ time python amicable-numbers-1000000.py 
> 220 284
> 1184 1210
> 2620 2924
> ...
> 802725 863835
> 879712 901424
> 898216 980984
>
> real  0m15.282s
> user  0m15.276s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Условия вопроса запрещают использовать списки. Со списками можно было бы сделать [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) с которым задача для миллиона решается за полторы секунды, а для десяти миллионов за шестнадцать секунд.

Comment: Большое спасибо  за подробный и полезный ответ!

Answer (score 3):

такое решение вас устраивает?

```
def getSum(value):
    res = 1
    for i in range(2, int(value**0.5) + 1):
        if value % i == 0:
            res += i + value // i
    return res

for i in range(10, 10000):
    sum1 = getSum(i)
    sum2 = getSum(sum1)
    if sum2 == i and sum1 != sum2:
        print(i, sum1)
```

вычисление суммы множителей выполняется максимально быстро (скорость sqrt(N))
т.е. чтобы найти все делители не надо проходить от `1` до `N / 2`, достаточно пройти от `2 до sqrt(N)` найдя 2 делителя - основной и второй, который равен частному от числа и найденного основного делителя

специально не выводятся такие числа как 28 (число равно сумму делителей)

недостаток - будут дубликаты (без списков эту проблему не решить), т.е. будет найдено `220 284` и `284 220`

Можно использовать функцию `sum`, но тогда неявно все таки используются списки:

```
for value in range(10, 10000):
    sum1 = 1 + sum((i + value // i) for i in range(2, int(value**0.5) + 1) if value % i == 0)
    sum2 = 1 + sum((i + sum1 // i) for i in range(2, int(sum1**0.5) + 1) if sum1 % i == 0)
    if sum2 == value and sum1 != sum2:
        print(value, sum1)
```

P.S.

кстати правильнее обрабатывать по другому полные квадраты, ведь по приведённому выше алгоритму корень как множитель складывается 2 раза

```
def getSum(value):
    res = 1 + (0 if int(value**0.5)**2 != value else int(value**0.5))
    for i in range(2, int(value ** 0.5)):
        if value % i == 0:
            res += i + value // i
    return res
```

теперь для `25` вместо неправильных `11` выдается правильные `6`

Comment: "... но тогда неявно все таки используются списки!". Нет, в вашем коде нет списков, только генераторы, а они не хранят промежуточные результаты в памяти. Как только генератор порождает число оно сразу же поступает в сумматор и выбрасывается.

Comment: Вторую сумму в главном цикле можно считать только если первая сумма больше `i`. Это экономит четверть времени.

Comment: `int(value**0.5)` -> `math.isqrt(value)`.

Comment: от дубликатов можно избавиться с помощью `sum1 < sum2`

Comment: да, точно, не подумал про меньше-больше